# Error: KeyUsage does not allow digital signatures - Java-applet + mutual SSL

Tags: iis-7, ssl, applet, x509certificate, pki

We have developed a webbased Java application running in Tomcat under IIS on Windows 2008. The website has 2-way (mutual) SSL enabled in IIS requiring the client to authenticate using a x.509 certificate (PKI) as part of SSL and this works fine with all our certificates using IE.

The website also has a java-applet called ViewOne ImageViewer. This works fine with 2-way SSL with some of our certificates but with others we get the exception on the client (java 1.6) during SSL-handshake after the user has selected its authentication certificate:

> security: KeyUsage does not allow
>   digital signatures

The most obvious difference between the certificates are that EKU (Extended Key Usage) are not present on the certificates failing. The certificate working has the EKU "Client Authentication - 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2".

Does anyone know if the EKU 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 is needed to run a java applet or if this can be set somewhere?
Or could the error be because of something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean when you say talk about working/failing certificates. There are 3 certificates involved here: one on the server, one of the client and one for the applet's signature.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am talking about the client certificates, both originating from the same CA. If i use client-cert A it works fine but if i use client-cert B it does not. The difference between them seem to be the EKU but maybe it is something else that i am missing. I am trying to find out why there is a difference and if there is some way to configure java to care about the same cert-properties as IE/Windows does. The client-certs are placed on endusers smartcards and not easily replaced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard normally used to validate a certificate are in [RFC 5280: Internet X.509 Public Key Infrastructure Certificate and Certificate Revocation List (CRL) Profile](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280). Certificates can have (at least) two extensions about their usage: [Key Usage](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.3) and [Extended Key Usage](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.12).

- Key Usage

The Key Usage extension doesn't talk specifically about client-certificates. However, if this extension is present, the `digitalSignature` flag must be set, since during the SSL/TLS handshake, the `CertificateVerify` TLS message is signed with the private key for this certificate. This is required according to this section of RFC 5280:

> The digitalSignature bit is asserted
> when the subject public key
> is used for verifying digital signatures, other than signatures on
> certificates (bit 5) and CRLs (bit 6), such as those used in an
> entity authentication service, a data origin authentication
> service, and/or an integrity service.

(Most cipher suites will require `keyAgreement` too.)

- Extended Key Usage

This one if more specific about client-certificates (if the extension is present, which is recommended but not always the case):

> ```
>    id-kp-clientAuth             OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-kp 2 }
>    -- TLS WWW client authentication
>    -- Key usage bits that may be consistent: digitalSignature
>    -- and/or keyAgreement
> ```

You can find more details about this in [this NSS technical note](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/tech-notes/tn3.html) (this should apply across other products).

When you get "*security: KeyUsage does not allow digital signatures*", it seems to indicate that the (non-extended) Key Usage is present in the certificate you're trying to use as a client-certificate, but that `digitalSignature` isn't enabled. (That's something that the CA the issued these certificates should have done.)

This is not related to the applet. However, it's possible that the URL of the applet itself is protected with client-certificate authentication, which would fail because of these extensions.

One the server side, since you're running this behind IIS, it's IIS that handles the TLS/SSL certificate verification. Apache Tomcat shouldn't really care about where it got the certificate from. (In Java, you'd be able to tweak the way you verify the certificate by configuring custom `TrustManager`s, but that would only apply if Java (JSSE) was handling the SSL/TLS connection itself; it doesn't apply when Tomcat is behind IIS, Apache Httpd or even when it uses APR.)
I'm not sure how to configure this with IIS, but there is an option in [netsh http add sslcert](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725882%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_2) called `[ usagecheck= ] enable | disable`, which sounds like it could help. It might be too lenient, though. (Use with caution.)

This being said, it seems that you get the error on the client side, before the certificate is even sent. I must admit I haven't tried, but you might be able to use a specific `KeyManager` that would force the use of that certificate. I'm not entirely sure whether this would work.

Just as a side note, signing applet is a different matter. To sign an applet, the certificate needs to have the Extended Key Usage for *anyExtendedKeyUsage* or for *id-kp-codeSigning*. (Signing will work otherwise, but running the applet won't.) You can find more information here: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5056088

Comment: Thanks alot Bruno for this great information! This will surely help us get much closer to finding the problem much faster. Now i will fokus on invstigating the KeyUsage flags and not so much the EKU.

Comment: Thanks also.   As a footnote for (gnuTLS) `certtool` users the thing to do here is use `--template` with `signing_key` in the template of the cert that you want to be able to validate, e.g., to a node which has the CA cert that fulfilled the cert request (search `man certtool` for `digitalSignature`).